# MySQL Query for looping with certain condition

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I have this data. This is a record of meeting time

Created_by is user_id
I want to count the total hours of room used. The system add new data based on every user that join the room.
So, actually the meeting in this room has 4 sessions, which is:

1. 14:53:33 (id 6) until 15:10:48 (id 8)
2. 15:14:01 (id 12) until 15:15:37 (id 12)
3. 15:14:48 (id 13) until 15:14:48 (id 13)
4. 15:15:37 (id 14) until 15:15:37 (id 14)
   **I need the result to be 4 rows like above, instead of 10 rows like the data**.

Room session 2-4 is just user 27 trying to testing the room 
After some breakdown, the condition has to fulfill is like this :
1. grouping by room_id 
2. check if :
a. record first started at (FSA) and first ended at (FEA)
CONDITION:
A. If 
started at between FSA and FEA
AND
ended at between FSA and FEA
THEN
CONTINUE

B. If
started at between FSA and FEA
AND
ended at > FEA
replace FEA with new ended_at

C. If 
started at > FEA
AND
ended at > FEA
THEN
append new row and record new FSA and new FEA

Can you recommend the query that looping to compare in order the meet the conditions above ?
I'm having trouble finding the right query. 
Please share your thoughts on this problem.
Cheers, Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested queries to find the result:

- tagged - find rows after which is a new session
- summarized - mark rows in the same session

---

```
with tagged 
as (
  select *, case when lead(started_at) over w < max(ended_at) over w then 0 else 1 end tag, row_number() over w as rn
  from meeting
  window w as (partition by room_id order by started_at asc)
),
summarized 
as (
  select *, sum(tag) over (partition by room_id order by rn desc) tag_summary
  from tagged
)
select room_id, min(started_at) started_at, max(ended_at) ended_at
from summarized 
group by room_id, tag_summary
order by room_id, started_at
;

-- data scripts

create table meeting (
 id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
 room_id int unsigned not null,
 started_at datetime not null,
 ended_at datetime not null
);

insert into meeting ( room_id, started_at, ended_at )
values
  ( 373, '2021-10-22 14:53:33', '2021-10-22 15:10:47')
, ( 373, '2021-10-22 14:56:06', '2021-10-22 14:56:47')
, ( 373, '2021-10-22 14:59:53', '2021-10-22 15:10:48')
, ( 373, '2021-10-22 15:00:28', '2021-10-22 15:10:10')
, ( 373, '2021-10-22 15:00:50', '2021-10-22 15:10:41')
, ( 373, '2021-10-22 15:01:32', '2021-10-22 15:01:33')
, ( 373, '2021-10-22 15:14:01', '2021-10-22 15:14:01')
, ( 373, '2021-10-22 15:14:24', '2021-10-22 15:14:48')
, ( 373, '2021-10-22 15:15:37', '2021-10-22 15:15:37')
;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cca43c3937be7a884dc906615b5a9c3a

Comment: thankyou ! was excepted to used windows function but can not think of that way, thanks, very helpful !

Answer (score -1):

3.6.5.5 LOOP Statement

```
[begin_label:] LOOP
    statement_list
END LOOP [end_label]
```

LOOP implements a simple loop construct, enabling repeated execution of the statement list, which consists of one or more statements, each terminated by a semicolon (;) statement delimiter. The statements within the loop are repeated until the loop is terminated. Usually, this is accomplished with a LEAVE statement. Within a stored function, RETURN can also be used, which exits the function entirely.

Neglecting to include a loop-termination statement results in an infinite loop.

A LOOP statement can be labelled. For the rules regarding label use, see Section 13.6.2, “Statement Labels”.

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE doiterate(p1 INT)
BEGIN
  label1: LOOP
    SET p1 = p1 + 1;
    IF p1 < 10 THEN
      ITERATE label1;
    END IF;
    LEAVE label1;
  END LOOP label1;
  SET @x = p1;
END;
```